# How to read Crashlytics?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, crashlytics, google-fabric

I just get to know Fabric and integrated it into my project and trying to see how it brings value to me. I've used [Crashlytics.crash()](https://github.com/corymsmith/react-native-fabric), and got the below "error log" but I'm wondering what language is that and how do we really able to understand it

```
# Crashlytics - plaintext stacktrace downloaded by Isaac Lem at Thu, 18 Oct 2018 08:41:53 GMT
# URL: https://fabric.io/mobile111539583220/ios/apps/com.xx.xx-xx/issues/5bc84705f8b88c29633d3016?time=last-seven-days/sessions/1aexxeedddasdasd7b5f3bfb444d69e_DNE_0_v2
# Organization: Mobile
# Platform: ios
# Application: xx
# Version: 1.2.0 (1)
# Bundle Identifier: com.xx.xx-xx
# Issue #: 1
# Issue ID: 5bc84705f8b88c29633d3016
# Session ID: 1aec4083e612462ea7b5f3bfb444d69e_DNE_0_v2
# Date: 2018-10-18T08:39:00Z
# OS Version: 12.0.0 (17G65)
# Device: iOS (Simulator)
# RAM Free: 5.9%
# Disk Free: 22%

#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  xx                        0x10161a106 -[Crashlytics crash] + 4
1  xx                        0x10152aecb -[SMXCrashlytics crash] (SMXCrashlytics.m:42)
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1071eb11c __invoking___ + 140
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1071e85b5 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 325
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1071e8a06 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 54
5  xx                        0x100f5907a -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] (RCTModuleMethod.mm:544)
6  xx                        0x1010107f6 facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&) (RCTNativeModule.mm:99)
7  xx                        0x10101030f facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)::$_0::operator()() const (RCTNativeModule.mm:71)
8  xx                        0x101010289 ___ZN8facebook5react15RCTNativeModule6invokeEjON5folly7dynamicEi_block_invoke (RCTNativeModule.mm:65)
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x10839f51d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x1083a0587 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x1083ac3bc _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1290
12 CoreFoundation                 0x1071477f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
13 CoreFoundation                 0x107141e86 __CFRunLoopRun + 2342
14 CoreFoundation                 0x107141221 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
15 GraphicsServices               0x10bc351dd GSEventRunModal + 62
16 UIKitCore                      0x10f763115 UIApplicationMain + 140
17 xx                        0x100e60f20 main (main.m:14)
18 libdyld.dylib                  0x108410551 start + 1

--

#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  xx                        0x10161a106 -[Crashlytics crash] + 4
1  xx                        0x10152aecb -[SMXCrashlytics crash] (SMXCrashlytics.m:42)
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1071eb11c __invoking___ + 140
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1071e85b5 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 325
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1071e8a06 -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 54
5  xx                        0x100f5907a -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] (RCTModuleMethod.mm:544)
6  xx                        0x1010107f6 facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&) (RCTNativeModule.mm:99)
7  xx                        0x10101030f facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)::$_0::operator()() const (RCTNativeModule.mm:71)
8  xx                        0x101010289 ___ZN8facebook5react15RCTNativeModule6invokeEjON5folly7dynamicEi_block_invoke (RCTNativeModule.mm:65)
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x10839f51d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x1083a0587 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x1083ac3bc _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1290
12 CoreFoundation                 0x1071477f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
13 CoreFoundation                 0x107141e86 __CFRunLoopRun + 2342
14 CoreFoundation                 0x107141221 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
15 GraphicsServices               0x10bc351dd GSEventRunModal + 62
16 UIKitCore                      0x10f763115 UIApplicationMain + 140
17 xx                        0x100e60f20 main (main.m:14)
18 libdyld.dylib                  0x108410551 start + 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest that adding more custom logs for `crashlytics`. You could find document in [Enhance Crash Reports](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html).

Some bug could be fixed with `stack trace` information, but many bugs need more custom logs to figure out why they crash.

---

An crash example image, which includes custom logs inside.

[image: Custom Logs]

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! will definitely check them out thanks!