# iOS App Crashes pointing to Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric, crash

I am slightly confused, I am getting few crashes from my application where the crash logs has the following information too.

Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception

Does this means that, its a crash from Fabric library or its a valid crash?

In the stack trace , there are some references to my application as well.
Please check the following. The stacktrace points to "MYAPP" is pointing to my application.

```
Crashed: com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.exception
0  MYAPP                   0x101419040 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1565424
1  MYAPP                   0x101419040 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1565424
2  MYAPP                   0x101418efc CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1565100
3  MYAPP                   0x1014096bc CLSHandler + 1501548
4  MYAPP                   0x101417114 __CLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke + 1557444
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x1a925b484 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x1a9208610 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
7  MYAPP                   0x101416bb8 CLSExceptionRecord + 1556072
8  MYAPP                   0x1014169ec CLSExceptionRecordNSException + 1555612
9  MYAPP                   0x10141660c CLSTerminateHandler() + 1554620
10 libc++abi.dylib                0x1a89e40fc std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
11 libc++abi.dylib                0x1a89e3a40 __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*) + 130
12 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1a89f0b84 _objc_exception_destructor(void*) + 378
13 Foundation                     0x1aa2b478c _NSInitializePlatform + 54
14 CoreFoundation                 0x1a97551e8 __CFReallocationFailed + 92
15 CoreFoundation                 0x1a9755188 __CFSafelyReallocate + 68
16 CoreFoundation                 0x1a97751d8 __CFDataGrow + 336
17 CoreFoundation                 0x1a97744c0 CFDataReplaceBytes + 340
18 CoreFoundation                 0x1a97a3da0 _CFAppendXML0 + 2536
19 CoreFoundation                 0x1a97a3f74 _CFAppendXML0 + 3004
20 CoreFoundation                 0x1a97a3ce8 _CFAppendXML0 + 2352
21 CoreFoundation                 0x1a97a3f74 _CFAppendXML0 + 3004
22 CoreFoundation                 0x1a97a3ce8 _CFAppendXML0 + 2352
23 CoreFoundation                 0x1a97a3f74 _CFAppendXML0 + 3004
24 CoreFoundation                 0x1a97a061c _CFPropertyListCreateXMLData + 184
25 CoreFoundation                 0x1a97a2540 CFPropertyListCreateData + 200
26 Foundation                     0x1aa1d8820 +[NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:format:options:error:] + 48
27 Foundation                     0x1aa201b30 -[NSDictionary(NSDictionary) writeToFile:atomically:] + 180
28 MYAPP                   0x1012bdba8 -[ADEumANRDetection initialAnrDetection] + 142936
29 MYAPP                   0x1012bd2cc -[ADEumANRDetection anrThreadProcess] + 140668
30 Foundation                     0x1aa2d23b0 __NSThread__start__ + 1040
31 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a943c2fc _pthread_body + 128
32 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a943c25c _pthread_start + 48
33 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1a943fd08 thread_start + 4
```

Comment: How about [adding more custom logs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52871334/419348) to trace the reason why?

Comment: The area which is pointing to MyApp is from a third party Framework (AppDynamics). Now I am totally confused , becoz not sure whether its happening from AppDynamics for Fabric.

Comment: `0  MYAPP                   0x101419040 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1565424` isn in you `MYAPP`. I suppose to the crash is due to `MYAPP`, not 3rd party.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a problem with the Crashlytics library, you should [upgrade](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios) to a newer library. I changed from Crashlytics 3.14.0 to 3.12.0, and my problem was fixed.

```
  pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.10.2'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.14.0'
```